# Alternative to `wxProcess::IsInputAvailable`

Tags: c++, linux, wxwidgets

According to [the documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_process.html#aac0e3a571fb7959b83ef3a82ec306342), the method `wxProcess::IsInputAvailable` *"allows writing simple (and extremely inefficient) polling-based code waiting for a better mechanism in future wxWidgets versions."* It also points to an example code dated to "15.01.00", I've checked [on GitHub](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blame/master/samples/exec/exec.cpp) that the usage of this method dates back some 16 years or more.

> **Well, is this method of pooling still inefficient? Is there any better alternative?**

I'm debugging an issue with a process's output not being read using something similar to the exec sample, and either way my application is sensitive to the timeliness of this polling and extracting of output.

Comment: what platform? wx version?

Comment: @Igor  I'm using wxWidgets 3.1.3, coding in and for linux. Language is C++.

Comment: I presume you are using this method. Does it takes time to complete? What hardware you are running it on?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the methods for reading the redirected output or the child process are inefficient.  I think the document is stating that polling on the GUI thread as in the sample will be inefficient since it involves repeatedly generating pseudo idle events.

A possible alternative is to use a secondary thread to do the reading.  Here is an example of using the lame mp3 encoder to encode a wav file:

```
// For compilers that support precompilation, includes "wx/wx.h".
#include "wx/wxprec.h"

#ifdef __BORLANDC__
    #pragma hdrstop
#endif

// for all others, include the necessary headers (this file is usually all you
// need because it includes almost all "standard" wxWidgets headers)
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    #include "wx/wx.h"
#endif

#include <wx/filename.h>
#include <wx/filepicker.h>
#include <wx/msgqueue.h>
#include <wx/thread.h>
#include <wx/process.h>

const char* pathToLame = "d:\\temp\\lame.exe";

wxDEFINE_EVENT(wxEVT_THREAD_STDIN, wxThreadEvent);
wxDEFINE_EVENT(wxEVT_THREAD_STDERR, wxThreadEvent);

class LameThread : public wxThread
{
    public:
        enum ThreadMessage
        {
            ProcessComplete,
            ExitThread,
            MessageLast
        };

        LameThread(wxEvtHandler*, wxProcess*, wxMessageQueue<ThreadMessage>& q);
        ~LameThread();

    private:
        ExitCode Entry() wxOVERRIDE;
        void DrainInput();

        wxMessageQueue<ThreadMessage>& m_queue;
        wxEvtHandler* m_handler;
        wxProcess* m_process;
        char* m_buffer;
        size_t m_bufferSize;
};

LameThread::LameThread(wxEvtHandler* h, wxProcess* p,
                       wxMessageQueue<ThreadMessage>& q)
           :wxThread(wxTHREAD_JOINABLE),m_queue(q)
{
    m_process = p;
    m_handler = h;
    m_bufferSize = 1024*1024;
    m_buffer = new char[m_bufferSize];
}

LameThread::~LameThread()
{
    delete[] m_buffer;
    delete m_process;
}

wxThread::ExitCode LameThread::Entry()
{
    ExitCode c;

    while ( 1 )
    {
        // Check if termination was requested.
        if ( TestDestroy() )
        {
            wxProcess::Kill(m_process->GetPid());
            c = reinterpret_cast<ExitCode>(1);
            break;
        }

        ThreadMessage m = MessageLast;
        wxMessageQueueError e = m_queue.ReceiveTimeout(10, m);

        // Check if a message was received or we timed out.
        if ( e == wxMSGQUEUE_NO_ERROR )
        {
            if ( m == ProcessComplete )
            {
                DrainInput();
                c = reinterpret_cast<ExitCode>(0);
                break;

            }
            else if ( m == ExitThread )
            {
                wxProcess::Kill(m_process->GetPid());
                c = reinterpret_cast<ExitCode>(1);
                break;
            }
        }
        else if ( e == wxMSGQUEUE_TIMEOUT )
        {
            DrainInput();
        }
    }

    return c;
}

void LameThread::DrainInput()
{
    if ( !m_process->IsInputOpened() )
    {
        return;
    }

    wxString fromInputStream, fromErrorStream;
    wxInputStream* stream;

    while ( m_process->IsInputAvailable() )
    {
        stream = m_process->GetInputStream();
        stream->Read(m_buffer, m_bufferSize);
        fromInputStream << wxString(m_buffer, stream->LastRead());
    }

    while ( m_process->IsErrorAvailable() )
    {
        stream = m_process->GetErrorStream();
        stream->Read(m_buffer, m_bufferSize);
        fromErrorStream << wxString(m_buffer, stream->LastRead());
    }

    if ( !fromInputStream.IsEmpty() )
    {
        wxThreadEvent* event = new wxThreadEvent(wxEVT_THREAD_STDIN);
        event->SetString(fromInputStream);
        m_handler->QueueEvent(event);
    }

    if ( !fromErrorStream.IsEmpty() )
    {
        wxThreadEvent* event = new wxThreadEvent(wxEVT_THREAD_STDERR);
        event->SetString(fromErrorStream);
        m_handler->QueueEvent(event);
    }
}

class MyFrame: public wxFrame
{
    public:
        MyFrame();

    private:
        void OnClose(wxCloseEvent& event);
        void OnEncode(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void OnProcessComplete(wxProcessEvent& event);
        void OnThreadInput(wxThreadEvent&);

        wxThread* m_lameThread;
        wxMessageQueue<LameThread::ThreadMessage> m_msgQueue;
        wxFilePickerCtrl* m_filePicker;
        wxTextCtrl* m_textCtrl;
        wxButton* m_encodeButton;
};

MyFrame::MyFrame()
        :wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "Encode", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(600, 400))
{
    m_lameThread = NULL;

    wxPanel* panel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
    m_filePicker = new wxFilePickerCtrl(panel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString,
                                     "Select a file", "*.wav");
    m_textCtrl = new wxTextCtrl(panel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString,
                                wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize,
                                wxTE_DONTWRAP|wxTE_MULTILINE|wxTE_READONLY);
    m_encodeButton = new wxButton( panel, wxID_ANY, "Encode");

    wxBoxSizer* sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

    sizer->Add(m_filePicker, wxSizerFlags().Expand().Border(wxALL) );
    sizer->Add(m_textCtrl,
               wxSizerFlags(1).Expand().Border(wxLEFT|wxRIGHT|wxBOTTOM));
    sizer->Add(m_encodeButton,
               wxSizerFlags().Border(wxLEFT|wxRIGHT|wxBOTTOM).Right());

    panel->SetSizer( sizer );
    panel->Layout();

    m_encodeButton->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MyFrame::OnEncode, this);
    Bind(wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW, &MyFrame::OnClose, this);
    Bind(wxEVT_END_PROCESS, &MyFrame::OnProcessComplete, this);
    Bind(wxEVT_THREAD_STDIN, &MyFrame::OnThreadInput, this);
    Bind(wxEVT_THREAD_STDERR, &MyFrame::OnThreadInput, this);
}

void MyFrame::OnClose(wxCloseEvent& event)
{
    if ( m_lameThread && m_lameThread->IsRunning() )
    {
        m_msgQueue.Post(LameThread::ExitThread);
        m_lameThread->Wait();
        delete m_lameThread;
    }

    Destroy();
}

void MyFrame::OnEncode(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    // Make sure the input file exists and is a wav file.
    wxString file = m_filePicker->GetPath();

    if ( !wxFileName::FileExists(file) )
    {
        m_textCtrl->AppendText("file does not exist.\n");
        return;
    }

    wxFileName fn(file);

    if ( fn.GetExt() != "wav" )
    {
        m_textCtrl->AppendText("File is not a wav file.\n");
        return;
    }

    // Create a process and and encoder thread.
    wxProcess* process = new wxProcess(this);
    process->Redirect();

    m_msgQueue.Clear();
    m_lameThread = new LameThread(this, process, m_msgQueue);
    m_lameThread->Run();

    if ( !m_lameThread->IsRunning() )
    {
        m_textCtrl->AppendText("Unable to launch encoder thread.\n");
        delete m_lameThread;
        return;
    }

    // Execute the encoder command.
    wxString cmd = pathToLame;
    cmd << " \"" << fn.GetFullPath() << "\" \"";
    cmd << fn.GetPathWithSep() << fn.GetName() << ".mp3\"";

    wxExecute(cmd, wxEXEC_ASYNC, process);
    m_encodeButton->Disable();
}

void MyFrame::OnProcessComplete(wxProcessEvent& event)
{
    if ( m_lameThread && m_lameThread->IsRunning() )
    {
        m_msgQueue.Post(LameThread::ProcessComplete);
        m_lameThread->Wait();
        delete m_lameThread;
        m_lameThread = NULL;
        m_encodeButton->Enable();
    }
}

void MyFrame::OnThreadInput(wxThreadEvent& event)
{
    m_textCtrl->AppendText(event.GetString());
}

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
    public:
        virtual bool OnInit()
        {
            ::wxInitAllImageHandlers();
            MyFrame* frame = new MyFrame();
            frame->Show();
            return true;
        }
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
```

On windows, this looks like this:

[image]

The basic idea is to run a tight loop in the thread's `Entry` method.  In each iteration the thread waits for a message from a message queue, and if no message is received the thread tries to check the process for input or error messages.

That's essentially the same polling technique as used in the sample, but since it's in a secondary thread it won't clog the gui thread with idle events.  If you need to do any processing of the input, that will also be done on the secondary thread.

If you're having trouble with timings, you can reduce the time spent waiting on the message queue.

Note that launching the secondary procss and receiving the event when it finishes can only be done on the main thread.

Finally I should mention that I'm not 100% sure this is completely thread safe.  I wish there was a way to protect the reads and writes with the input and error streams with a mutex or critcal section; but since all the writing to those streams is done under the hood, I can't see any way to do that from user code.  I can say I've used this technique on both windows and linux in the past without issue.